# My Python Django button is not appearing when someone logs in(it should be)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am working on a Python Django project. I'm currently working on a way for myself to log in and create a product card for this project store. The create button should only appear when I am logged in. It's just not appearing. I go to Inspect the web page and I don't even see the code for my button. I have no idea what is happening and some help would be awesome!

This is the block of code that should be producing said button. If the user is authenticated, it'll create this create button under each one of my categories. I originally had the for statement over the if statement and I switched it to see if that would change anything and nothing happened.

HTML

```html
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            {% for category in categories %}
                <p>User is authenticated: {{ user.username }}</p> <!--LINE FOR DEBUGGING-->
                <p>Category: {{ category.name }}</p> <!--LINE FOR DEBUGGING-->
                <a class="create_button" href="{% url 'create_product' category.id %}">Create {{ category.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

One of the first things I did I was add some debugging lines to see if it actually understood I was logged in.

HTML

```html
<div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <p>User is authenticated: {{ user.username }}</p> <!-- LINE FOR DEBUGGING -->
            {% else %}
                <p>User is not authenticated</p> <!-- LINE FOR DEBUGGING -->
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

That seemed to work perfectly fine. When I log in, I see a line of text that says I'm authenticated. I made sure to check my Urls.py as well.

`path('create_product/<int:category_id>/', views.create_product, name='create_product'),`
It certainly seems pretty alright to me, though I could be wrong. Lastly this is my create_product function. When I have finished creating said product it should return you to the home page.

PYTHON

```py
def create_product(request, category_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.category = category
            product.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'app/create_product.html', {'form': form, 'category': category})
```

I even have a css class for the button and set the z-index and color of it, so I know it should be appearing, but it simply isn't. I even tried removing the z-index at some point and nothing changed.

CSS

```
.create_button {
    z-index: 1;
    color: blue;
}
```

I'm so confused. And to top it off if I type http://localhost:8000/create_product/1/ or http://localhost:8000/create_product/ to see if I can just directly go and create a product, it says the page ain't even found. That it looked through my urls and the current path create_product/ didn't match any of my urls. Maybe I'm overthinking this, idk. If I am a gentle slap on the face would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It look like you didn't provide the `categories` parameter in the template. When the templates are rendered, no buttons are added, If `categories` is None.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out. Ngl I can't believe I forgot that. In my "create_product" I added "categories = Category.objects.all()" then where my return render is I added a "'categories': categories". I went back to my page and no button. Am I misunderstanding haha?

Comment: @Cristina please provide your full code of rendering the template.

Comment: Yeah of course. Sorry about that.

Comment: def create_product(request, category_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.category = category
            product.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'app/create_product.html', {'form': form, 'category': category, 'categories': categories})

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, cause I figured it out and rewrote a lot of my code. If you are someone having a similar issue, this was my fix. I updated my models for one.

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = {
     ('APPAREL', "Apparel"),
     ('TOYS', "Toys"),
     ('PETS', "Pets"),
     }



class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/', null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=60, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=1)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The next thing I did was udpate my create_product view.

```
def create_product(request):
    form = ProductForm(data=request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    content = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/create_product.html', content)
```

I fixed my urls

```
path('create_product/', views.create_product, name='create_product'),
```

Then lastly got rid of the category.id in my button.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="create_button" href="{% url 'create_product' %}">Create</a>
        {% endif %}
```